# What are the most active users Upvote/Downvote ratio, and who receives the most downvotes?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

The following comment has 3 Upvotes:

> *"**@DVK** You're the highest-rep user on this site. Somehow I doubt that the community is being unfair to you and **user1873**(who is the third highest-rep user)"*-– <strike>REDACTED</strike>

**So I wondered, Is the community being unfair to DVK and me?**

Let's define downvotes received as a percentage of all downvotes on the site as "being unfair." This won't be a perfect measure, since some people will argue that other actions may/may not be fair, but at least the purpose of [downvoting](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down) is well defined, it requires some investment in the site before you can do it, normally isn't supposed to happen much:

> **Vote Down** - Awarded At: 125 Reputation
>
> **When should I vote down?**: Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.

- **How may downvotes do DVK and I have as a percentage of all downvotes and compared to other users?**
- **What is the Upvote-to-Downvote ratio for each user?**

Comment: I equally downvote questions that are seeking to prove a point but try to disguise themselves as asking for information, and answers that contain opinion.  I do not care who posts it.  And it is not just on this SE that I do it.

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly, this took me a while to parse - I had to keep reminding myself that the vote totals you are showing are the downvotes *received* not given.

**What you are saying**

What your list is showing is this:

- 8% of the people who have taken the time to consider your answer and are motivated enough to spend a point of reputation have found your answers unsatisfactory for some reason. (Note: That means 92% have found what you said to be useful.)
- 7% have said the same of DVK
- 2% have said the same of me

I'm going to go out on a limb and say the three of us are responsible for many of the answers on this site - about equal. Because you raised the question, and because I am choosing to answer it, I am going to confine my analysis to just User1873 and AffableGeek.  I like DVK, and don't want to drag him into this.

**The possibilities**

Since these votes are coming from the entire audience, we only have a few options:

1. There is a conspiracy to downvote User1873 and not AffableGeek
2. There is a qualitative difference between AffableGeek's answers and User1873's.

I will leave it to the other moderators to answer #1 - but suffice it to say, the voting patterns do not support theory #1.  And, as Sherlock Holmes would say, when you eliminate the possibilities, the other possibilities, no matter how improbable, must be the truth.

**The difference between the answers**

I do see one qualitative difference between your answers and mine - and I think even you alluded to it in a [very good question you asked on meta](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1410/do-you-want-to-help-politics-se-we-need-your-help-in-suggesting-neutral-wording?rq=1), asking for help in making a NPOV. Were I not drowning in personal business, I would like to have answered you more directly there.

And that, my friend, is the difference.  I would suggest you compare my answers with yours, objectively.  You do a much better job of bringing in facts and figures, but your tone seems downright hyperbolic.  I, on the other hand, am not nearly as thorough in you as documenting my assumptions.  Frankly, I should be chastised for that - or at very least, you *should* be getting more votes - except for this.

<sup>(Warning: The following may be seen as tooting my own horn. I apologize in advance, but I really am trying to be helpful here.)</sup>

I would argue that if you look at the facts I state, I tend to use more center-of-the-road, verifiable type statistics when I do. I make much less bold claims and assertions.  I tend to add very little to the interpretation thereof.  And, I go out of my way to be kind to my opponents.  I try to be very clear about what's my opinion (and I keep very little of that in there), and very long on more commonly accepted truths.  (I'm still wondering why the only vote I received on a Clausewitz quote was negative!) As a preacher, I am exceedingly mindful of the old adage "[Weak point, pound pulpit.](http://fellowshiproom.org/2010/05/29/pound-the-pulpit/)"

**Description > Perscription**

This stems from my experience at Christianity.SE.  The assumption there is that there are some things we aren't going to agree on, and other things we will.  We [focus less on "truth"](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1696/are-truth-questions-inherently-off-topic-or-just-a-bad-question-smell) than on what is.  Put another way, we are descriptive and not perspective. [That is what makes us different, and I think better than most religious forums.](http://tinyurl.com/csedifferent)

Your tone is almost always prescriptive.  "We should do X".  My tone is almost always descriptive. "People do Y."  Prescription alienates people, and causes them to downvote.  Description, whether good or bad, tends to illuminate.

I would argue for everybody - from top to bottom - that description in and of itself is what SE does well. Anything less is Quora. Be descriptive and less partisan (and I applaud you for your steps in that direction), and I think you'll see that 8% drop significantly.

Comment: Okay, what is the correction? A downvote costs you a point of rep.  Is there something more that needs to be said there?

Comment: "Your tone is almost always perspective. 'We should do X.'" I have never made any such proclamations. It isn't my fault that reality and the data back up my answers? As for the questions, you are saying people are downvoting **because they don't like the tone**, not because the question is sloppy, no effort, or dangerously incorrect. Then we agree, people are using downvoting incorrectly.

Comment: A downvote means [whatever the downvoter wants it to mean](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1871/what-purpose-does-downvoting-questions-serve).

Comment: Indeed, we cannot control why people downvote. We can only use data like mine posted here that shows a pattern of how people are using their downvotes. I wonder why no one has suggested any fixes to the **tone** of my other posts? If wrong are to believe that my **tone in those questions** is the issue, there are about 30 questions with downvotes, but zero helpful suggestions (besides my own example one, curiously enough this still has -6 downvotes **after the tone fixes** ).

Comment: " and I think you'll see that 8% drop significantly." You see, that is the problem with relying on feelings instead of data. When I have evidence to the contrary, I might believe your predictions.

Comment: I think that the only way the 8% will come down is if @user1873 improves the quality of the questions they ask and answers they post.

Answer (score -1):

[Disparate impact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disparate_impact) is a legal theory that an adverse impact that works to the disadvantage of a minority group. It doesn't mean that the majority group is given preference, but there is the potential for discrimination. DVK and I received slightly over 15% of all downvotes. DVK mostly for his answers, and I mostly for my questions. The reason why this haven't had much impact on our reputation is that there is a 5:1 ratio for Upvotes versus Downvotes. The last column is the percentage of Downvotes the user has of all downvotes on the site. I will let the numbers speak for themselves.

```
Name              |Vot| DV|U/D| -Q| Q |-Q/Q| -A| A |-A/A| 1383 Total Downvotes
------------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+----+-------+
user1873          |217| 68|31%|83 |64 |1.29|28 |73 |0.38| 8.03% |
DVK               |774|210|27%|17 |58 |0.29|84 |147|0.57| 7.03% |
Anixx             | 82| 27|33%|19 |10 |1.9 |51 |44 |1.16| 5.06% |
gerrit            |274|10 | 4%|34 |75 |0.45| 8 |20 |0.4 | 3.04% |
Sam I am          |138| 65|47%|12 |24 |0.5 |28 |43 |0.65| 2.89% |
DA.               |208| 88|42%| 1 | 2 |0.5 |34 |41 |0.83| 2.53% |
Affable Geek♦     |472|18 | 4%|15 |34 |0.44|13 |80 |0.16| 2.02% |
------------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+----+-------+
Vot: total votes from a user.
DV: Downvotes from a user
U/D: Downvotes as a percentage of all votes.
-Q: Downvotes received by user for Questions.
Q: Total questions by user.
-A: Downvotes received by user for Answers.
A: Total answers by user.
```

The table below is organized by tap users ratio of Downvotes/All Votes. I broke the table up into several ratios 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/5, 1/6. Some things stand out in the table. Too many active users have very high Downvote/All Vote ratios, even some Moderator.

```
Name              |Vot| DV|U/D| -Q| Q |-Q/Q| -A| A |-A/A|
------------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+----+-------+
Robert Cartaino♦  | 65| 51|78%| - | - | -  | 0 | 3 |0.0 | 0%    |
Persian Cat       |141| 84|60%| 16| 9 |1.77| 5 | 1 |5.0 | 1.52% |
DJClayworth       |195|103|53%|  2| 5 |0.4 |16 |33 |0.48| 1.16% | 
------------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+----+-------+
Downvotes >= 50% of all votes
Name              |Vot| DV|U/D| -Q| Q |-Q/Q| -A| A |-A/A|
------------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+----+-------+
Chad              |362|180|50%| 8 |13 |0.62|13 |28 |0.46| 0.78% |
Sam I am          |138| 65|47%|12 |24 |0.5 |28 |43 |0.65| 2.89% |
dcaswell          | 13|  6|46%| - | - | -  | 1 | 4 |0.25| 0.07% |
toscho            | 28| 12|43%| - | - | -  | - | 1 |0.0 | 0%    |
DA.               |208| 88|42%| 1 | 2 |0.5 |34 |41 |0.83| 2.53% |
Yannis Rizos♦     |378|135|36%| 2 | 6 |0.33| 5 |39 |0.13| 0.51% |
Mad Scientist     | 14|  5|36%| 2 | 4 |0.5 | - | - | -  | 0.14% |
------------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+----+-------+
Downvotes >= 33.3% of all votes
------------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+----+
Name              |Vot| DV|U/D| -Q| Q |-Q/Q| -A| A |-A/A|
------------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+----+-------+
Andrew Grimm      | 42| 14|33%|11 |17 |1.65| 0 | 2 |0.0 | 1.23% |
Anixx             | 82| 27|33%|19 |10 |1.9 |51 |44 |1.16| 5.06% |
user1873          |217| 68|31%|83 |64 |1.29|28 |73 |0.38| 8.03% |
John Bensin       | 13|  4|31%| - | - | -  | 0 | 2 |0.0 | 0%    |
Samuel Russell    | 59| 17|28%| 4 | 7 |0.57| 2 |14 |0.14| 0.43% |
------------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+----+-------+
Downvotes >= 25% of all votes
Name              |Vot| DV|U/D| -Q| Q |-Q/Q| -A| A |-A/A|
------------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+----+-------+
DVK               |774|210|27%|17 |58 |0.29|84 |147|0.57| 7.03% |
JNK               |153| 35|23%| - | - | -  | 8 |  8|1.0 | 0.58% |
ymar              | 22|  5|23%| 3 |13 |0.23| - | - | -  | 0.22% |
LateralFractal    | 46| 10|22%| 1 | 4 |0.25| 2 | 13|0.15| 0.22% |
Lennart Regebro   | 56| 12|21%| - | - | -  | 1 |  3|0.33| 0.07% |
------------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+----+-------+
Downvotes >= 20% of all votes
Name              |Vot| DV|U/D| -Q| Q |-Q/Q| -A| A |-A/A|
------------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+----+-------+
Eugene Seidel     | 42| 8 |19%| - | - | -  | 0 | 2 |0.0 | 0%    |
Sklivvz♦          | 29| 5 |18%| 5 |11 |0.45| 0 | 3 |0.0 | 0.36% |
------------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+----+-------+
Downvotes >= 16.7% of all votes
Name              |Vot| DV|U/D| -Q| Q |-Q/Q| -A| A |-A/A|
------------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+----+
Michael Kingsmill♦|258|39 |15%| 3 |16 |0.19|14 |48 |0.29| 1.23% |
Keen              |122|14 |11%| 1 | 3 |0.33| 0 | 1 |0.0 |
Lohoris           |210|21 |10%| 0 | 4 |0.0 | 0 | 1 |0.0 |
Łukasz L.         |116|12 |10%| 2 | 4 |0.5 | 7 |19 |0.37|
UKB               | 96|10 |10%| 1 | 3 |0.33| 2 | 5 |0.4 |
Bobson            | 98|10 | 9%| 0 | 1 |0.0 | 2 |10 |0.2 |
Sven Clement      |121|11 | 9%| 6 |17 |0.35| 7 |21 |0.33| 
Steve Melnikoff   |168|12 | 7%| 0 | 1 |0.0 | 0 |11 |0.0 |
Affable Geek♦     |472|18 | 4%|15 |34 |0.44|13 |80 |0.16| 2.02%
gerrit            |274|10 | 4%|34 |75 |0.45| 8 |20 |0.4 | 3.04%
dan04             |211| 9 | 4%| 0 | 1 |0.0 | 0 | 8 |0.0 |
Martin Schröder   |180| 5 | 3%| - | - | -  | 0 | 1 |0.0 |
TRiG              |121| 4 | 3%| 1 | 3 |0.33| - | - | -  |
------------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+----+
Name              |Vot| DV|U/D| -Q| Q |-Q/Q| -A| A |-A/A|
------------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+----+
JKor              |116| 1 | 0%| 0 | 1 |0.0 | 0 | 3 |0.0 |
SteB              |106| 0 | 0%| 0 | 1 |0.0 | 0 |2- |0.0 |
Mechanical snail  | 95| 1 | 0%| 1 | 3 |0.33| 0 | 3 |0.0 |
PearsonArtPhoto   | 93| 0 | 0%| 0 | 5 |0.0 | 1 | 8 |0.13|
Gilles            | 92| 0 | 0%| - | - | -  | - | - | -  |
Mathankumar       | 79| 1 | 1%| 0 | 1 |0.0 | 1 | 8 |0.13|
Graham Wager      | 70| 3 | 4%| 1 | 2 |0.5 | 0 | 3 |0.0 |
Alberto Bonsanto  | 64| 3 | 5%|11 |20 |0.55| 1 | 7 |0.14| 
Ryathal           | 60| 3 | 5%| 0 | 0 |0.0 | 8 |15 |0.53|
mikeazo           | 58| 4 | 7%| 0 | 7 |0.0 | 1 | 6 |0.17|
Lizz              | 54| 0 | 0%| - | - | -  | 3 | 1 |3.0 |
StasM             | 53| 7 |13%| - | - | -  | 7 |10 |0.7 |
------------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+----+
Name              |Vot| DV|U/D| -Q| Q |-Q/Q| -A| A |-A/A|
------------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+----+
Tim Post♦         | 53| 4 | 8%| 0 | 2 |0.0 | 0 | 1 |0.0 |
Avi               | 52| 6 |12%| 3 | 2 |1.5 | 4 |12 |0.33|
Daniel Standage   | 50| 1 | 2%| - | - | -  | - | - | -  |
Casebash          | 50| 3 | 6%| 0 | 3 |0.0 | 1 | 5 |0.2 |
Kevin Peno        | 44| 3 | 7%| - | - | -  | 0 | 4 |0.0 |
Stephen Collings  | 44| 0 | 0%| 0 |11 |0.0 | - | - | -  |
wbogacz           | 44| 0 | 0%| 0 | 1 |0.0 | 0 | 1 |0.0 |
Mark Hurd         | 44| 0 | 0%| - | - | -  | - | - | -  |
Michael Mrozek    | 42| 5 |12%| - | - | -  | 0 |13 |0.0 |
sncrmck           | 42| 0 | 0%| - | - | -  | 0 | 4 |0.0 |
Roc Martí         | 39| 0 | 0%| 1 | 0 |0.0 | - | - | -  |
Taymon            | 37| 3 | 8%| 0 | 1 |0.0 | 1 | 7 |0.14|
Yury              | 34| 0 | 0%| - | - | -  | - | - | -  |
JohnFx            | 32| 0 | 0%| - | - | -  | 0 | 3 |0.0 |
Snakes and Coffee | 29| 2 | 7%| 8 | 9 |0.88| - | - | -  |
------------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+----+
Name              |Vot| DV|U/D| -Q| Q |-Q/Q| -A| A |-A/A|
------------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+----+
Tom Au            | 28| 2 | 7%| 4 | 4 |1.0 |11 |28 |0.39| 1.08% |
Scott Pack        | 28| 0 | 0%| - | - | -  | - | - | -  |
kbelder           | 28| 0 | 0%| - | - | -  | - | - | -  |
arne.b            | 27| 2 | 7%| 0 | 1 |0.0 | 0 | 4 |0.0 |
Fela Winkelmolen  | 26| 0 | 0%| 2 | 3 |0.66| 5 |10 |0.5 |
mmyers            | 26| 0 | 0%| - | - | -  | 0 | 1 |0.0 |
dbjohn            | 25| 0 | 0%| - | - | -  | - | - | -  |
CsBalazsHungary   | 24| 0 | 0%| 1 | 5 |0.20| 0 |11 |0.0 |
ctype.h           | 21| 1 | 5%| 1 | 1 |1.0 | - | - | -  |
Y22               | 21| 0 | 0%| - | - | -  | - | - | -  |
Jeremy Holovacs   | 20| 2 |10%| 2 | 2 |1.0 | 2 | 5 |0.40|
Tiago Cardoso     | 20| 0 | 0%| - | - | -  | - | - | -  |
nairboon          | 19| 0 | 0%| 3 | 3 |1.0 | - | - | -  |
Zetta Suro        | 19| 1 | 5%| 3 | 2 |1.5 | - | - | -  |
Brock Adams       | 18| 3 |17%| - | - | -  | 0 | 3 |0.0 |
bhau              | 18| 2 |11%| 3 | 6 |0.5 | 0 | 1 |0.0 |
------------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+----+
Name              |Vot| DV|U/D| -Q| Q |-Q/Q| -A| A |-A/A|
------------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+----+
Nate              | 18| 3 |16%| - | - | -  | 0 | 1 |0.0 |
Joe Z.            | 18| 0 | 0%| - | - | -  | 0 | 1 |0.0 |
amcnabb           | 18| 1 | 6%| - | - | -  | - | - | -  |
Joost             | 16| 0 | 0%| 0 | 2 |0.0 | 1 | 5 |0.2 |
mootinator        | 16| 0 | 0%| - | - | -  | 0 | 1 |0.0 |
jrg               | 16| 0 | 0%| - | - | -  | 0 | 1 |0.0 |
segiddins         | 16| 0 | 0%| 1 | 3 |0.33| - | - | -  |
nic               | 16| 0 | 0%| 0 | 3 |0.0 | - | - | -  |
Astyanax          | 16| 0 | 0%| 0 | 1 |0.0 | - | - | -  |
user54609         | 16| 0 | 0%| - | - | -  | - | - | -  |
Brendan           | 15| 0 | 0%| - | - | -  | 2 | 7 |0.29|
Dunk              | 15| 1 | 7%| - | - | -  | 7 | 3 |2.33|
Rodrigo Guedes    | 15| 0 | 0%| - | - | -  | - | - | -  |
Mark Booth        | 15| 0 | 0%| - | - | -  | - | - | -  |
Garreh            | 15| 0 | 0%| - | - | -  | - | - | -  |
------------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+----+
Name              |Vot| DV|U/D| -Q| Q |-Q/Q| -A| A |-A/A|
------------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+----+
WilliamKF         | 14| 0 | 0%| 3 | 8 |0.38| - | - | -  |
KJ Tsanaktsidis   | 14| 2 | 7%| 1 | 3 |0.33| 0 | 1 |0.0 |
deworde           | 14| 1 | 7%| - | - | -  | - | - | -  |
Xaqron            | 14| 1 | 7%| - | - | -  | - | - | -  |
Seçkin Savaşçı    | 14| 1 | 7%| - | - | -  | - | - | -  |
Viliam Búr        | 13| 1 | 8%| - | - | -  | 4 | 3 |1.33|
Merbs             | 13| 1 | 8%| 0 | 2 |0.0 | - | - | -  |
iowatiger08       | 13| 0 | 0%| - | 1 |0.0 | - | 3 |0.0 |
Trylks            | 12| 1 | 8%| 2 | 4 |0.5 | 2 | 4 |0.5 |
Ben Brocka        | 12| 1 | 8%| - | - | -  | - | - | -  |
Manishearth       | 12| 0 | 0%| - | - | -  | - | - | -  |
Isaac Moses       | 12| 0 | 0%| - | - | -  | - | - | -  |
draks ...         | 12| 0 | 0%| - | - | -  | - | - | -  |
Derfder           | 12| 0 | 0%| 9 | 7 |1.29| 8 |  4|2.0 | 1.23% |
Sinan Ünür        | 11| 1 | 9%| - | - | -  | 3 | 10|0.33|
------------------+---+---+---+---+---+----+---+---+----+
Name              |Vot| DV|U/D| -Q| Q |-Q/Q| -A| A |-A/A|
```

Comment: @user1873 Pardon my obversation, but it seems to me as though your answers are among the less downvoted answers, and dvk's answers tend to be average regarding downvote ratio

Comment: @user1873 Dvk's questions are some of the least downvoted questions, and the one outlier is that your questions are among the highest downvoted

Comment: Seems the data says you ask bad questions and DVK provides bad answers..